# Синглтон и тестирование

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

В общем есть следующий код, состоящий из синглтона и класса, использующего его (упрощенная версия).

```
public final class Singleton {
    private static Singleton s_instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return s_instance;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return "string";
    }

    public String getStringTest(){
        return "string_test";
    }
}


public class SomeClass{
    private String someString;

    public SomeClass(){
        someString = Singleton.getInstance().getString();
    }
}
```

Синглтон считывает конфигурацию из файла и предоставляет методы для ее получения компонентами программы (`getString()` и т.п.).

Для тестирования работы класса `SomeClass` мне нужно, чтобы он получил другое значение при вызове `getString()`, а именно то, которое вернет `getStringTest()`.

Я хотел бы иметь что-то типа такого, но столкнулся с тем, что не знаю, как создать `mock` или `spy` объект для синглтона:

```
when(Singleton.getInstance().getString()).thenReturn(Singleton.getInstance().getStringlTest());
```

Ну и как следствие вопрос: Как можно создать `mock` или `spy` объект для синглтона или как по-другому можно подменить возвращаемое синглтоном значение? Java, jUnit4.

Comment: Вот поэтому синглтон ещё часто антипатерном называют. Почитайте про  DI (dependency injection)

Answer (score 1):

Mockito, мне кажется, прекрасно справится с Вашей задачей.

```
Singleton singleton = mock(Singleton.class);
when(singleton.getStringTest()).thenReturn("What you need");
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведу самый эффективный, пусть и не очень красивый (и очень непопулярный) вариант тестирования Singleton.

**Шаг 1.** Добавьте метод `Singleton.setInstance` и сделайте конструктор `Singleton` защищенным:

```
public final class Singleton {
    private static Singleton s_instance = new Singleton();

    public static setInstance(Singleton instance) {
        s_instance = instance;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Шаг 2.** Мокните класс `Singleton` любым способом и задайте полученный объект через `Singleton.setInstace`

**Шаг 3.** Протестируйте класс `SomeClass`.

---

А когда у вас появится время для выплаты технического долга, выполните еще один шаг:

**Шаг 4.** Проведите рефакториг класса `SomeClass`, выкинув любое использование метода `Singleton.getInstance`. Инжектируйте экземпляр `Singleton` в `SomeClass` в явном виде.